# Model with name of a gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there any way to generate model with the name rack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact, I don't recommend you to do that even you find how. It'll make your life more complicated :)

Answer (score 2):

No. Just like `Object` or `Kernel`, `Rack` is a reserved constant name, because it already exists and is required for Rails to function properly.